# How does this bash script for suspending work?

Tags: suspend, hibernate, wakeup

Please explain how `DESIRED` and `NOW` are being used, as well as what `%` is doing.

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: suspend_until HH:MM"
    exit
fi

# Check whether specified time today or tomorrow
DESIRED=$((`date +%s -d "$1"`))
NOW=$((`date +%s`))
if [ $DESIRED -lt $NOW ]; then
    DESIRED=$((`date +%s -d "$1"` + 24*60*60))
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`%s` is a *format specifier* for the `date` command. From `man date`

```
   %s     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
```

The code appears to be checking whether the requested HH:MM has already passed in the current day, and if so is rolling it over to the next calendar day.